# Android QR code reading libs

Tags: qr-code

I have an Android QR code reading app that runs on a cheap phone with no autofocus. QR code that I must read is small and on camera preview looks blurry. The one app able to read this code is NeoReader.
Does everybody know good free libraries to read QR codes?

I know that:

```
ZBar (it's ok but not works with blurry code)
ZXing (this Barcode reader not reads the required code; don't tried to integrate)
NeoReader SDK (not free)
```

My init code for ZBar:

```
scanner = new ImageScanner();
scanner.setConfig(0, Config.ENABLE, 0);
scanner.setConfig(Symbol.QRCODE, Config.ENABLE, 1);
scanner.setConfig(0, Config.X_DENSITY, 1);
scanner.setConfig(0, Config.Y_DENSITY, 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If none of the four above is an option (or even if they where!) I would strongly suggest using Googles own library found in Google Play services under the namespace `com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode`. It scans the codes locally, fast and robust, and you have full control of the source code in just a few classes.

For a simple example check out [Android QR Code Reader Made Easy](https://www.varvet.com/blog/android-qr-code-reader-made-easy/). That should get you up and running in no time! There's also further reading linked at the end of the post for advanced examples.